# Should I do a 'Task.Wait()' in a C# loop of sync and async methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have two methods I want to call within a loop. Step1() has to complete before Step2() is called. But in a loop, Step1() can start while Step2() is asynchronously executing. Should I simply wait for the Step2 task, before allowing any other 'Step2' tasks from being executed, as I do in the code below?

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    StartCommand = new RelayCommand(Start);
}

public ICommand StartCommand { get; set; }

private async void Start()
{
    await  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:hh:mm:ss.fff} - Started processing.");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            _counter++;
            string result = Step1(i);

            _step2Task?.Wait();     //Is this OK to do???

            Step2(result).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        _step2Task?.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:hh:mm:ss.fff} - Finished processing.");
    });
}

private string Step1(int i)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);   //simulates time-consuming task
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:hh:mm:ss.fff} - Step 1 completed - Iteration {i}.");

    return $"Step1Result{i}";
}

private async Task Step2(string result)
{
    _step2Task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(4000);  //simulates time-consuming task
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:hh:mm:ss.fff} - Step 2 completed. - {result}");

    });
    await _step2Task;
}
```

Comment: At first glance this looks very wrong.  Say precisely what the must-happen-before relationships are between all your tasks, and then insert `await`s -- not `Wait`s, which can deadlock -- at all the places where one task must complete before another begins.  Remember, `await` is the sequencing operation on a set of tasks; code after the `await` will not run until the task is complete.

Comment: And why is long-running operation Step1 not asynchronous?

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks for your responses. I'd like to make it asynchronous, but I'm modeling the situation I have in our production code (which puts all this on its own thread so it doesn't lock up the UI). I'm trying to avoid changing too much production code (I don't want to do 'async all the way up' if I can avoid it)

Comment: @Kevinosaurio In the future, when you make edits you questions you should try to fix _all appropriate edits that you can make_, especially if your only edit is just moving code to the left.

Comment: **Embrace asynchrony**. The whole *point* of proper asynchrony is that you can put it all on the UI thread without locking up the UI! The only thing you should be putting onto its own thread is CPU-bound work; wrap CPU-bound work up in a Task that manages the worker thread and await it from the UI thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do any of this stuff; you will risk getting deadlocks all over the place.  Also, don't move stuff onto threads unless it is CPU bound.

Start over:

- Find every long-running *synchronous* method that is CPU intensive and write an async wrapper around it.  The async wrapper should grab a worker thread, execute the CPU intensive task, and complete when the execution is done.  **Now you consistently have an abstraction in terms of tasks, not threads**.
- Move all of your control flow logic onto the UI thread.
- Put an `await` everywhere that you mean "the code that comes after this must not execute until the awaited task is complete".

If we do that, your code gets a lot simpler:

```
// Return Task, not void
// Name async methods accordingly
private async Task StartAsync()
{
  Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:hh:mm:ss.fff} - Started processing.");
  Task task2 = null;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
     // We cannot do Step2Async until Step1Async's task 
     // completes, so await it.
     string result = await Step1Async(i);
     // We can't run a new Step2Async until the old one is done:
     if (task2 != null) {
       await task2;
       task2 = null;
     }
     // Now run a new Step2Async:
     task2 = Step2Async(result);
     // But *do not await it*.  We don't care if a new Step1Async
     // starts up before Step2Async is done.
  }
  // Finally, don't complete StartAsync until any pending Step2 is done.
  if (task2 != null) {
    await task2;
    task2 = null;
  }
  Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:hh:mm:ss.fff} - Finished processing.");
}

private string Step1(int i)
{
   // TODO: CPU intensive work here
}

private async Task<string> Step1Async(int i) {
  // TODO: Run CPU-intensive Step1(i) on a worker thread
  // return a Task<string> representing that work, that is
  // completed when the work is done.
}

private void Step2(string result)
{
  // TODO: CPU-intensive work here
}

private async Task Step2Async(string result) 
{
  // TODO: Again, make a worker thread that runs Step2
  // and signals the task when it is complete.
}
```

Remember, **await is the sequencing operation on workflows**.  It means **don't proceed with this workflow until this task is complete; go find some other workflow**.

Exercise: How would you write the code to represent the workflow:

- Step1 must complete before Step2
- Any number of Step2 may be running at the same time
- All the Step2 must complete before Start completes

?